# How to specify a custom parameters.xml when building a Web Deploy package for ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, webdeploy

### Overview

I am building a deployable web package that can be imported into IIS that automatically prompts for settings needed by my ASP.NET Core application.  I already created a package that will deploy just fine, except after deploying, I need to manually find/edit my appsettings.json file.

I know this package can include a `parameters.xml` file that will automatically prompt and fill in my appsettings.json when importing an app into IIS.  I have already made a parameters.xml file, and manually added it to my package after building it; it worked as expected.  I'd just like to have msbuild automatically add the parameters.xml file to the package for me.

A separate project of mine (ASP.NET MVC 4) already does this.  For that, I simply needed to put my `parameters.xml` in the same folder as my .csproj.  I tried doing the same here, but had no luck.

### Repro Steps

I created an ASP.NET Core Web Application [image: ASP.NET Core Web Application]
Using .NET Framework on ASP.NET Core 1.1
[image: .NET Framework with ASP.NET Core 1.1]
I then went to publish my website

[image: Publish dropdown]

Selected 'Folder' (just to get a template)
[image: Folder Publish]

I then edited the profile and changed the `WebPublishMethod` to `Package` and added the three lines below it.

```
<DesktopBuildPackageLocation>bin\$(Configuration)\$(MSBuildProjectName).zip</DesktopBuildPackageLocation>
<PackageAsSingleFile>true</PackageAsSingleFile>
<DeployIisAppPath>External</DeployIisAppPath>
```

[image: Modified publish profile]

I then published one more time.  Now I get a WebDeploy package that I can deploy to IIS.

Great!  but...

I'd like to customize the parameters.xml.

[image: Parameters.xml I'd like to customize]

For previous projects, I was able to add a `parameters.xml` file to my project root, and VS/msbuild would automatically add it to my published package.  This currently works for a different project using ASP.NET MVC 4.

So, I tried the same thing for this project.  First I added a settings.json with a very simple setting:

```
{
  "SettingName": ""
}
```

Then I added a `parameters.xml` file that I know works to my project root.  (If I manually replace the parameters.xml file in Sample.zip package, it correctly prompts and replaces my setting when deploying)

```
<parameters>
  <parameter name="IIS Web Application Name" value="External" tags="IisApp">
    <parameterEntry kind="ProviderPath" scope="IisApp" match="^c:\\users\\joshs\\documents\\visual\ studio\ 2017\\Projects\\Sample\\Sample\\obj\\Release\\net461\\win7-x86\\PubTmp\\Out\\$" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter name="Setting Name" description="Enter a custom app setting" defaultValue="Default Setting Value">
    <parameterEntry kind="TextFile" scope="obj\\Debug\\net461\\win7-x86\\PubTmp\\Out\\appsettings\.json$" match="(?&lt;=\&quot;SettingName\&quot;\s*:\s*\&quot;)[^\&quot;]*" />
  </parameter>
</parameters>
```

Again, I right click and `Publish` once more.  This time with the parameters.xml file.

[image: Project structure with Publish menu shown]

I expect the Sample.zip to contain the parameters.xml that I added to my project root, but it does not.  It is the exact same as from my original publish.

### Question

**During the build process when creating a web deploy package, how do you include custom settings in the parameters.xml?**

### I have already tried this...

I already looked at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46338042/2494785, but with no luck, though my command differed slightly from the original poster.

```
PS C:\Users\joshs\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Sample> & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\E
nterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe' .\Sample.sln /t:Sample /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile /p:
ProjectParametersXMLFile="C:\Temp\parameters.xml"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve this from peteawood's comment from an issue posted on GitHub.

https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/issues/201#issuecomment-349990389

In ASP.NET Core 2.0+ you can add the following to your .csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    .
    .
    <Target Name="AddMoreParameters" AfterTargets="_CreateParameterFiles">
        <Copy SourceFiles="Parameters.xml" DestinationFiles="$(_MSDeployParametersFilePath)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

`SourceFiles` should point to the location of your `parameters.xml` file from the perspective of the `.csproj` file.  My `parameters.xml` is found in the same directory as my project file.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this solution removes default parameter `IIS Web Application Name` which is required for IIS deployment. Based on the linked issue, it should be fixed in SDK 2.2.

Comment: @JanZahradník do you have a link to the issue  that you can share?

Answer (score 3):

I believe I can just pass parameters via cmd-line as properties for msbuild.
It's not fully what you asked for I understand.
For example, in the following command I'm passing `DeployIisAppPath` property:

```
dotnet publish /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:DeployIisAppPath=mysite/myapp /p:PublishProfile=rnddev03-core-dev
```

and in the output folder we'll get xxx.SetParameters.xml file with:

```
<parameters>
  <setParameter name="IIS Web Application Name" value="mysite/myapp" />
</parameters>
```

Comment: You're correct; you can pass properties directly to msbuild.  Executing a command line statement is fine by me, though I'm not following how that would help in this case.  Would you elaborate a bit, please?

Comment: @JoshSchultz I'm sorry, probably I not enough carefully read you question :(, you're talking about custom parameters, I doubt it's possible to configure them via msbuild properties directly.